# How could I differentiate a finite sum of a sequence with respect to particular element?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a summation: `Sum (i from 1 to N) A_i`, `A_i` is the ith element of a sequence. But when I do differentiation with respect to `A_N`, Mathematica returns `N` instead of 1.

How could I do it right?

Comment: If you can post just enough code to show what you are doing then someone might be able to see how to solve the problem

Comment: assume he's done this: `D[ Sum[ a[i], {i, n}] , a[i] ] -> n`. Simple answer mathematica doesn't support such operations on abstract(unspecified n) sums.  Correct answer is not `1` it is `1 if i is an integer in range 1,n` ..

Comment: I also doubted mathematica may not support unspecified sums. Thank you for confirming that.